# AngularJS and Websocket

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, angularjs-service

I am trying to create a simple echo test application wherein I have, connect and disconnect buttons. Whenever I click on connect, I want to create an object of websocket. I am doing that in a service. But somehow, after creating an object onopen is not getting fired. I am new to this. Can someone help me? thanks.
Here's my code

HTML Code

```
<button class="echo-test-button" id ="connect" ng-click ="connect()">
        Connect
    </button>
    <button class="echo-test-button" id ="disconnect" ng-click ="disconnect()">
        Disconnect
    </button>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module("test");
app.controller('SocketCtrl',["$scope","$window","Socket","$rootScope",
    function ($scope, $window, socket, $rootScope) {

    $scope.connect = function () {

        socket.createConnection();
    }

    }]);
```

Socket Service

```
angular.module("test").factory("Socket",["$http","$q", function ($http, $q) {
    var ws = {};
    var socket = {
        url :  "ws://echo.websocket.org/",

    };
    socket.createConnection = function() {
        ws = new WebSocket(socket.url);
    };
    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log("Established");
    }
    return socket;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onopen handler is not setup propertly. Move the onopen handler inside the createConnection method.

```
angular.module("test").factory("Socket",["$http","$q", function ($http, $q) {
    var ws = {};
    var socket = {
        url :  "ws://echo.websocket.org/",

    };
    socket.createConnection = function() {
        ws = new WebSocket(socket.url);
        ws.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log("Established");
        }
    };
    return socket;
}]);
```

Comment: How can I send confirmation to client that socket is established? is there any good way?

Comment: @dhamchan By sending ack message on the same socket to the client from the server. Maybe from the onopen function as ws socket is still accessible in that.

Comment: @vijaykrishnavanshi, can you please edit your code and show it to me? How to send ack?  I am new to this.